# CakePHP 3.7.1 DispatchShell Not Executing Migrations Shell

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.7

I customized the cakephp app console/installer.php file for cakephp app 3.4.x and I am trying to upgrade it to 3.7.1, however, the following code is no longer working...

```
            $shell->dispatchShell([
                'command' => 'migrations migrate',
                'extra' => []
            ]);
```

It throws the following error

```
[Cake\Console\Exception\MissingShellException]
Shell class for "Migrations" could not be found. If you are trying to use a plugin shell, that was loaded via $this->addPlugin(), you may need to update bin/cake.php to match https://github.com/cakephp/app/tree/master/bin/cake.php
```

When I execute bin/cake migrations, I get

```
└──╼ bin/cake migrations
Migrations plugin, based on Phinx by Rob Morgan. 0.4.3
```

According to the documentation, it should still work, shouldn't it?

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/shells.html#invoking-other-shells-from-your-shell

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Try using `migrations.migrations`, ie pass the plugin prefix. Alternatively try the new command runner suggested in the error message.

Comment: Using migrations.migrations worked, thank you

Comment: Actually, it worked, yes, it installed the migrations to the database, but then it still throws the error after it's done.. which halts execution...

Comment: I had to explicitly load the migrations plugin in bootstrap for it to work